# Server-side rendering for authentication based on local storage

Tags: firebase, next.js, single-page-application, server-side-rendering

I have a Next.js app that uses Firebase for authentication. For reasons we have to configure Firebase to use local storage to store the auth data (so cookies are not an option). My current approach is to render the same generic skeleton for both authenticated users and guests.

Given the server doesn't know if the user is authenticated or not, I have two questions:

- How can a setup like this benefit from SSR, in addition to the generic loading screen I already implemented?
- My application's home page is only viewable by authenticated user, so I marked my entire page component `'use client';`. Next.js is unhappy about this; it suggests that I push the `'use client';`s to leaf components. Is my use case a legit reason to make the entire page a client component, given it's only viewable by authenticated user and therefore requires reading local storage?